# How to test if constexpr is evaluated correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have used constexpr to calculate hash codes in compile times. Code compiles correctly, runs correctly. But I dont know, if hash values are compile time or run time. If I trace code in runtime, I dont do into constexpr functions. But, those are not traced even for runtime values (calculate hash for runtime generated string - same methods).
I have tried to look into dissassembly, but I quite dont understand it

For debug purposes, my hash code is only string length, using this:

```
constexpr inline size_t StringLengthCExpr(const char * const str) noexcept
{
    return (*str == 0) ? 0 : StringLengthCExpr(str + 1) + 1;
};
```

I have ID class created like this

```
class StringID
{
    public:
       constexpr StringID(const char * key);
    private:
       const unsigned int hashID;
}

constexpr inline StringID::StringID(const char * key)
        : hashID(StringLengthCExpr(key))
{

}
```

If I do this in program `main` method

```
StringID id("hello world");
```

I got this disassembled code (part of it - there is a lot of more from inlined methods and other stuff in main)

```
;;;     StringID id("hello world"); 

        lea       eax, DWORD PTR [-76+ebp]                     
        lea       edx, DWORD PTR [id.14876.0]                   
        mov       edi, eax                                     
        mov       esi, edx                                     
        mov       ecx, 4                                       
        mov       eax, ecx                                      
        shr       ecx, 2                                        
        rep   movsd                                            
        mov       ecx, eax                                      
        and       ecx, 3                                       
        rep   movsb                                            

// another code
```

How can I tell from this, that "hash value" is a compile time. I don´t see any constant like *11* moved to register. I am not quite good with ASM, so maybe it is correct, but I am not sure what to check or how to be sure, that "hash code" values are compile time and not computed in runtime from this code.

*(I am using Visual Studio 2013 + Intel C++ 15 Compiler - VS Compiler is not supporting constexpr)*

**Edit:**

If I change my code and do this

```
    const int ix = StringLengthCExpr("hello world");

    mov       DWORD PTR [-24+ebp], 11                       ;55.15
```

I have got the correct result

Even with this

change private hashID to public

```
 StringID id("hello world"); 
  // mov       DWORD PTR [-24+ebp], 11                       ;55.15

 printf("%i", id.hashID);
  // some other ASM code
```

But If I use private hashID and add Getter

```
  inline uint32 GetHashID() const { return this->hashID; };
```

to ID class, then I got

```
  StringID id("hello world"); 
  //see original "wrong" ASM code

  printf("%i", id.GetHashID());
  // some other ASM code
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, symbols starting with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved.

Comment: Did you turn optimizations on?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Ok.. thanks.

Comment: @Black This is debug build

Comment: If you can't tell the difference, why do you care?

Comment: try `constexpr size_t value = _StringLength("hello world");` do you see any changes on the assembly?

Comment: @MartinPerry: try 'constexpr StringID id = {"hello world"}; ' or something equivalent - tends to work for me on all the compilers where I tested it; hint: 'const' is not the same as 'constexpr'...

Answer (score 28):

The most convenient way is to use your `constexpr` in a `static_assert` statement. The code will not compile when it is not evaluated during compile time and the `static_assert` expression will give you no overhead during runtime (and no unnecessary generated code like with a template solution).

Example:

```
static_assert(_StringLength("meow") == 4, "The length should be 4!");
```

This also checks whether your function is computing the result correctly or not.

Comment: My "hash code" with length is only for this example. In real I have more complicated one. Doing this, I would have to calculate it manually for every string and for every change I made, so this is not a solution

Comment: Why would you have to calculate it manually? You test it with `static_assert` for one or two test values and there you go.

Comment: With this, I can only test output from constexpr function, but not directly hashID value (it is not constexpr and cant be) - static_assert(id.hashID == 11, "OK"); - compiler time error: expression must have a constant value

Comment: @Martin Perry `id.hashID` can not be known at compile time unless the `id` object is also a `constexpr`. The hash you calculate with your `constexpr` function has the same effect as if you would calculate the value by hand and insert it into your source code. It has no effect on the objects which are using it unless they are also `constexpr`s. If that is the case the `static_assert` can determine it.

Comment: For static_cassert no, but variable can be filled from constexpr function and I want to be sure, that it really is (and not in run time by function run)

Comment: I believe using `static_assert` forces compile-time evaluation of the of the `constexpr` function for the given values. But this does not guarantee that it will be evaluated for any other values that could be evaluated at compile-time. Or that the value generated will be used instead of rerunning the function at run-time.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to ensure that a `constexpr` function is evaluated at compile time, use its result in something which requires compile-time evaluation:

```
template <size_t N>
struct ForceCompileTimeEvaluation { static constexpr size_t value = N; };

constexpr inline StringID::StringID(const char * key)
        : hashID(ForceCompileTimeEvaluation<StringLength(key)>::value)
{}
```

Notice that I've renamed the function to just `StringLength`. Name which start with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, or which contain two consecutive underscores, are not legal in user code. They're reserved for the implementation (compiler & standard library).

Comment: But this will lost constexpr advantage, if value can not be evaluated at compile time (like StringID(some generated variable))

Comment: This is probably the best because at least Visual C++ is a bit unreliable for the array-of-N approach (and g++ is non-standard by default).

Answer (score 4):

In the future(c++20) you can use the [consteval](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) specifier to declare a function, which must be evaluated at compile time, thus requiring a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) context.

> The consteval specifier declares a function or function template to be
>   an immediate function, that is, every call to the function must
>   (directly or indirectly) produce a compile time constant expression.

An example from cppreference(see [consteval](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval)):

```
consteval int sqr(int n) {
  return n*n;
}
constexpr int r = sqr(100);  // OK

int x = 100;
int r2 = sqr(x);  // Error: Call does not produce a constant

consteval int sqrsqr(int n) {
  return sqr(sqr(n)); // Not a constant expression at this point, but OK
}

constexpr int dblsqr(int n) {
  return 2*sqr(n); // Error: Enclosing function is not consteval and sqr(n) is not a constant
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to force compile-time evaluation. But these aren't as flexible and easy to setup as what you'd expect when using `constexpr`. And they don't help you in finding if the compile-time constants are actually been used.

What you'd want for `constexpr` is to work where you expect it to beneficial. Therefor you try to meet its requirements. But Then you need to test if the code you expect to be generated at compile-time has been generated, and if the users actually consume the generated result or trigger the function at runtime.

---

I've found two ways to detect if a class or (member)function is using the compile-time or runtime evaluated path.

1. Using the property of `constexpr` functions returning `true` from the noexcept operator (`bool noexcept( expression )`) if evaluated at compile-time. Since the generated result will be a compile-time constant. This method is quite accessible and usable with Unit-testing.
   (Be aware that marking these functions explicitly `noexcept` will break the test.)

> [Source: cppreference.com (2017/3/3)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)
>   Because the noexcept operator always returns true for a constant expression, it can be used to check if a particular invocation of a constexpr function takes the constant expression branch (...)

2. *(less convenient)* Using a debugger: By putting a break-point inside the function marked `constexpr`. Whenever the break-point isn't triggered, the compiler evaluated result was used. Not the easiest, but possible for incidental checking.

> [Soure: Microsoft documentation (2017/3/3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constexpr-cpp)
>   Note: In the Visual Studio debugger, you can tell whether a constexpr function is being evaluated at compile time by putting a breakpoint inside it. If the breakpoint is hit, the function was called at run-time. If not, then the function was called at compile time.

I've found both these methods to be useful while experimenting with `constexpr`. Although I haven't done any testing with environments outside VS2017. And haven't been able to find an explicit statement supporting this behaviour in the current draft of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

The following trick can help to check if the constexpr function has been evaluated during compile time only:

With gcc you can compile the source file with assembly listing + c sources; given that both the constexpr and its calls are in source file try.cpp

```
 gcc -std=c++11 -O2 -Wa,-a,-ad  try.cpp  | c++filt >try.lst
```

If the constexpr function has been evaluated during run time time then you will see the compiled function and a call instruction (call function_name on x86) in the assembly listing try.lst (note that c++filt command has undecorated the linker names)

Interesting that it I always see a call if compiled without optimization (without -O2 or -O3 option).

Answer (score 1):

Simply put it in constexpr variable.

```
constexpr StringID id("hello world"); 
constexpr int ix = StringLengthCExpr("hello world");
```

A constexpr variable is always a real constant expression. If it compiles, it is computed on compile time.

Comment: This should be the best/easiest way to check if a function is evaluated at compile time. Note it only works since c++17.